# Getting FlowExecutionException when using JobExecutionDecider in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, jobexecutiondecider

I am new to Spring Batch . I implemented a `JobExecutionDecider` . Below is the code

```
@Component("customStepDecider")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CustomStepDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {

Environment environment;
private String executeStep;
public static  final String EXECUTE="EXECUTE";
public static  final String SKIP="SKIP";
@Override
public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
    if(Boolean.parseBoolean(environment.getProperty(executeStep)))
        return new FlowExecutionStatus(EXECUTE);
    else
        return new FlowExecutionStatus(SKIP);

}
public CustomStepDecider(String stepToExecute,Environment environment){
          this.executeStep=stepToExecute;
           this.environment=environment;}}
```

Below is the `Flow` that calls the `JobExecutionDecider`.The `Environiment` is already autowired and same is passed to `CustomStepDecider`

```
 @Bean(name = "customStepExecutionFlow")

    public Flow customStepExecutionFlow(){
        return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("customStepExecutionFlow")
                .start(new CustomStepDecider("file.executeStep1",env))
                .on("EXECUTE").to(step1)
                .from(new CustomStepDecider("file.executeStep2",env))
                .on("SKIP")
                .to(new CustomStepDecider("file.if214FileGenerationStep",env))
                .on("EXECUTE")
                .to(step2)
                .on("SKIP").end()
                .build();



    }
```

The functionality I need is the `JobExecutionDecider` first looks at properties file if it is false, it should skip step execution .If it is true it should execute the step.Below are my properties file

```
file.executeStep1=false
file.executeStep2=true
```

But whenever I am running I am getting the below error

```
 org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionException: Next state not found in flow=customStepExecutionFlow for state=customStepExecutionFlow.decision0 with exit status=SKIP
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error says you didn't specify the route for the case when your first `CustomStepDecider("file.executeStep1",env)` returns the `"SKIP"` exit status.

This should look something like

```java
    public Flow customStepExecutionFlow() {
        CustomStepDecider decider1 = new CustomStepDecider("file.executeStep1", env)
        ...
        return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("customStepExecutionFlow")
                .start(decider1).on("EXECUTE").to(step1)
                .from(decider1).on("SKIP").to(...) // or maybe .from(decider1).on("SKIP").end("COMPLETED")
                ...
                .build();
    }
```

The same should be done with the other deciders.